# Why are strings from text file cut by the FOR loop on passing them to another function?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**Prerequisites**

I have a file called `urls.txt` where I store my URLs, e.g.

```
www.google.de/test1.yaml?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster
www.google.de/test2.yaml?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster
www.google.de/test3.yaml?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster
```

**My goal**

Now I want to loop through these URLs and pass them to another function to download them.

```
:downloader
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (urls.txt) DO (call :sub_function %%i)
goto :eof

:sub_function
echo here url is: %~1
```

**Output**

The output is that it cuts off the query strings from the URLs and does not pass them completely to the next function.

For example, the output is: `www.google.de/test1.yaml?at`

What do I miss?

Comment: The use of Call expands the value of any variables in the for metavariable. 
Either incorporate the function into the for loop or Assign the value to a variable prior to calling the function

Comment: To elaborate, `%2Fheads%` get's interpreted as a variable as Call initiates an additional round of parsing.

Comment: The first thing you should do, as standard practice, when using your `call` command is to pass the argument to it as a single one, and the robust way of doing that is to doublequote it, i.e. ```Call  :sub_function "%%~i"```.

Comment: Instead of `call :sub_function %%i` you must use `call :sub_function "%%i"` in order to protect the `=`, which is a standard token separator for `cmd.exe` just like _space_, _tab_, `,` and `;`; moreover, `call` initiates a second `%`-expansion phase, but this can be prevented by assigning the argument string to a variable first and then letting it expand in the second phase, like `set "ARG=%%i" & call :sub_function "%%ARG%%"`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect special characters (like the `=`-sign in your situation, which constitutes a [standard token separator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) just like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,` and `;`), use quotation for the argument, so it is really treated as one.

Then the [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) initiates a second `%`-expansion phase, which is the reason why the `%`-signs in your argument cause issues (actually the sequence `%2` represents the second argument of your script). To circumvent that problem, store the argument string in a variable and ensure that is is going to be expanded during said second `%`-expansion phase.

Since URLs may also contain the `&`-symbol, the argument in the sub-function should not become expanded unquoted in order not to misinterpret it as the [command concatenation operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Here is the corrected code:

```cmd
:downloader
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (urls.txt) DO (
    set "ARG=%%i" & call :sub_function "%%ARG%%"
)
goto :eof

:sub_function
echo here url is: "%~1"
```